# Drop Down that gets populated by a list from the database. Need to Set a default value as text as first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "Data" page which gets populated after clicking on an add button on another page.
On loading of that Data page there are some drop down which gets loaded from the database. Below is the HTML which is used for that div which contain drop down .

```
<div class="divInputLabel">
            Organization Name<span class="requiredMark">|</span></div>
        <div class="divInput" style="height:40px;">
            <div id="divSbmsnOrganization" class="dropdown btn-group fav-dropdown pull-left popupLableDiv">
            </div>
        </div>
```

And below is the jquery and ajax call which set the value while loading of the date page:

```
   GetSubmissionOrganizationListData = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: oAuthUrl,
            type: "POST",  
            dataType: "json",
            data: {userId: gloggedInUserId},
            success: function (msg) {
                var header = signOAuthToken(msg); // get the oauth signature from the method
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST", // GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url : dataSubmissionServiceUrl + 'GetAppOrganizationsForDS',
                    data : {
                        userId : gloggedInUserId,
                        Appid : privileges.App.AppId,           
                        AppName :privileges.App.AppName ,
                        pReportingPeriodIDs:'',
                        appActionMappingId:0
                    },
                    dataType : "json", // Expected data format from server
                    processdata : false, // True or False
                    cache : false,
                    timeout:180000,async: false,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {                                   
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", header);
                    },
                    success : function(result) {// On Successfull service call
                        RenderInitiativeFilter(result, '#divSbmsnOrganization',
                        'SbmsnOrganization');
                        calling_GetAppOrganizations = false;
                        OrganizationSelectedIndexChanged(); 
                    },
                    error : function(res, errorString, exception) {
                        calling_GetAppOrganizations = false;
                        throw new Error("Method name: GetSubmissionOrganizationListData"+ " ServiceURL: "+ this.url+ " Error: "+ res.statusText);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(res, errorString, exception) {
                calling_GetAppOrganizations = false;
                throw new Error("Method name: GetSubmissionOrganizationListData"+ " ServiceURL: "+ this.url+ " Error: "+ res.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
```

In this, the result from the database has been set to the drop down and the first value from the database is set as the first value to that drop down.
I just need to put a default first value of that drop down field such as "Select an organization" and the database result list should be below that default message.
I am not sure how to do that, i have done with select tag where you can use "selected" but not sure int his case.
Could anyone help me in this case?

Comment: You can simply insert your default value at the top of the result you get from the database

Comment: Are you saying to add something like result[0] and giving the value to the drop down?

Comment: `result[0]` will replace the first value so you shouldnt do that, do `arr.splice(0, 0, item)` where item is your default value

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to prepend your value to the select list, it will add it to the beginning.

```
("#MySelectList").prepend($("<option></option>").val("SelectDefaultValue").html("SelectDefaultText"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not included your jquery to insert the results in the div but see below for how to have `disabled` options in your select element.

```html
<select>
  <option selected="selected" disabled>Please select</option>
  <option disabled>----</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The op didn't talk about disabled attribute but asked how to append a default value to the drop down list.

Comment: Just trying to help. He clearly has code that adds the select list but he hasn't posted it here. The fact that he mentioned using the select but wasn't sure of it suggested he needed clarification on the function of it.

Comment: The function RenderInitiativeFilter adds the list to that drop down div.

Comment: yes but you haven't included the code for that function, so we don't know what it does.